# R: Calculating the probability density function of a special definition of Skew-T Distribution

Tags: r, mixture-model

I currently work with the mixture model package `EMMIXskew` and I have fitted a skew-t Distribution on my data (some numerical vector).
The package has some density function `ddmst` but I haven't seen a probability density function in this package and I need some!

What I thought I could do is

1. use some other packages which provides a pdf for skew-t distribution, 
   like package `sn` with `pst`, but the problem is that this distribution
   has a different definition of skew-t distribution,
   OR
2. I could use `integrate` on `ddmst`, but it doesn't work so far.

I tried something like

```
library(EMMIXskew)

dat <- rdmst(n=1000,p=1,mean=0,cov=1,del=1)

mu=0.01
sigma=0.9
nu=1.1
del=3
pdmst <- function(x){     
  ddmst(x,n=length(dat),p=1,mean=mu,cov=sigma,nu=nu,del=del)
}

x=0.6

F_x <- integrate(pdmst,lower=-Inf,upper=x)
```

and also if I assume 3-modality of my data with parameters

```
mu=c(0.01,2,-0.4)
sigma=c(0.9,2,2.3)
nu=c(1.1,1,0.8)
del=c(3,2,1.2)
pdmst <- function(x){     
  ddmst(x,n=length(dat),p=1,mean=mu,cov=sigma,nu=nu,del=del)
```

I get this error

`Error in ddmix(dat, n, p, 1, "mst", mean, cov, nu, del) : dat does not match n and p.`

I really don't know what I did wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pdmst <- function(x){    
  ddmst(x,n=length(x),p=1,mean=mu,cov=sigma,nu=nu,del=del)
}
```

`n` should be the length of `x` instead of `dat`.
Then `pdmst(x)` should give you the density at `x`.

For the 3-component case, please refer to the documentation of `ddmix` on how to specify the arguments of this function.
For your second example, it can be entered as follows:

```
mu = cbind(0.01, 2, -0.4)
sigma = cbind(0.9,2,2.3)
del = cbind(3,2,1.2)
nu=c(1.1,1,0.8)
ddmix(x,1,1,3,"mst",mu, sigma, nu, del)
```

The final command should give you the logarithm of the density at `x` for each of the three components.